# VBA: object is closed error in sql query when using a join table

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am getting the error for the `ws.Cells(2, 2).CopyFromRecordset adoDbRs` line:

> operation is not allowed when the object is closed

If I remove the `JOIN` to the temp table `#reporttable`, it works fine, I feel like the recordset is empty because I'm sending it to a temp table and then trying to `JOIN` and pull out of that, but I'm not sure how to take the output from the final select query properly, it works fine when reformatted and typed directly into the SQL Server.

Secondary question:

Since I have been struggling with this, but can always get it working on the server, is there a way to setup a custom call to the SQL Server which is like `command(var1,var2,var3)` which runs a stored brick of working code on the SQL Server and returns what it returns, instead of my current process which is get it to work on the SQL Server and then struggle to adapt it into VBA?

```vb
Private Sub Run_Summary_Click()

Dim adoDbConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim adoDbRs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim selectCmd As New ADODB.Command

Dim Machvar As Integer
Machvar = Worksheets("SumImport").Range("A1").Value
Dim DateYMD As String
Dim DateStart As Date
Dim DateEnd As Date
Dim SQL As String
DateYMD = Format(Worksheets("SumImport").Range("A2").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")

' Open connection to the SQL Server database
 adoDbConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;   Data Source=********;  Initial Catalog=SMP;    User Id=Query;"

' Execute the select query
selectCmd.ActiveConnection = adoDbConn
   selectCmd.CommandText = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.#reporttable2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #reporttable2 " & _
    " SELECT " & _
    " DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101') as Date_Time " & _
    " ,max(Part_Count)-min(Part_Count) as PartsMade " & _
    " ,max(convert(char(5),  DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101'), 108)) as times " & _
    " ,max(Alarm_Light) as AlarmLight " & _
    " ,max(PV_Alarm) as AlarmCode " & _
    " INTO #reporttable2 " & _
    " FROM [33_TestImport]" & _
    " Where [DateTime]>= DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, '" & DateYMD & "')-0, 0) AND [DateTime]<= DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, '" & DateYMD & "')+24, 0) " & _
    " AND Machine_Number = " & Machvar & " " & _
    " Group BY DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101') " & _
    " select * " & _
    " from #reporttable2 p " & _
    " right join SMP.dbo.Timerange c " & _
    " ON c.mins = p.times " & _
    " order by mins "

Set adoDbRs = selectCmd.Execute(, , adCmdText)

' Clear the contents in cells where we're going to display the result
Dim cellRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("SumImport")
   ws.Activate
Set cellRange = Worksheets("SumImport").Range("B1:M1800")
   cellRange.ClearContents

' Activate the Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("SumImport")
   ws.Activate
' Put the query results starting from cell B2
ws.Cells(2, 2).CopyFromRecordset adoDbRs
' Set the column header
   ws.Cells(1, 2) = "DateTime"
   ws.Cells(1, 3) = "Part Total"
   ws.Cells(1, 4) = "TimeSync"
   ws.Cells(1, 5) = "Alarm Light"
   ws.Cells(1, 6) = "Alarm Code"
' Close the connection and free the memory
Set adoDbRs = Nothing
Set selectCmd = Nothing
   adoDbConn.Close
Set adoDbConn = Nothing
Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")
   ws.Activate

End Sub
```

And the code that works in SQL directly

```sql
drop table #reporttable2
declare @dateget as date
set @Dateget = '2020-03-19'

SELECT
    DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101') as Date_Time
    ,max(Part_Count)-min(Part_Count) as PartsMade
    ,max(convert(char(5),  DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101'), 108)) as times

into #reporttable2

FROM 
    [SMP].[dbo].[33_TestImport]

where [DateTime]>= DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, @Dateget)-1, 0)
    and [DateTime]<= DateAdd(Hour, DateDiff(Hour, 0, @Dateget)+24, 0)


GROUP BY
    DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101')

    select * 
    from #reporttable2 p
    right join SMP.dbo.Timerange c 
    ON c.mins = p.times
    order by mins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, ADO connections do not support multiple line SQL commands. Therefore, the recordset is possibly being created based on the very first line of SQL or the `DROP` statement and may not return anything.

However, looking closer at your situation, consider a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (CTE) and avoid the need of a temp table and then integrate a parameterized query for your date variable. Doing so, your original 5 statements convert to a single statement:

**SQL**

```sql
WITH reporttable2 AS (
   SELECT
       DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5) * 5, '20000101') AS Date_Time
       , MAX(Part_Count) - MIN(Part_Count) AS PartsMade
       , MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(5),  DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101'), 108)) AS times

   FROM 
      [SMP].[dbo].[33_TestImport]

   WHERE [DateTime] >= DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, @Dateget) - 1, 0)
     AND [DateTime] <= DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, @Dateget) + 24, 0)

   GROUP BY
       DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5) * 5, '20000101')
)

SELECT *
FROM reporttable2 p
RIGHT JOIN SMP.dbo.Timerange c 
   ON c.mins = p.times
ORDER BY mins
```

**VBA**

```vb
' ASSIGN DATE (NOT STRING) VARIABLE FOR PARAMETER
myDate = Worksheets("SumImport").Range("A2").Value

' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH QMARKS ?
sql = "WITH reporttable2 AS ( " _ 
      & " SELECT " _
      & "      DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5) * 5, '20000101') AS Date_Time " _
      & "      , MAX(Part_Count) - MIN(Part_Count) AS PartsMade " _
      & "      , MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(5),  DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5)*5, '20000101'), 108)) AS times " _
      & " FROM " _
      & "   [SMP].[dbo].[33_TestImport] " _
      & " WHERE [DateTime] >= DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, ?) - 1, 0) " _
      & "   AND [DateTime] <= DATEADD(Hour, DATEDIFF(Hour, 0, ?) + 24, 0) " _
      & " GROUP BY " _
      & "   DATEADD(MINUTE, (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '20000101', DateTime) / 5) * 5, '20000101') " _
      & ")" _
      & " " _
      & " SELECT * " _
      & " FROM reporttable2 p " _
      & " RIGHT JOIN SMP.dbo.Timerange c " _
      & "    ON c.mins = p.times " _
      & " ORDER BY mins"

With selectCmd
    .ActiveConnection = adoDbConn
    .CommandText = sql
    .CommandType = adCmdText

    ' BIND TWO PARAM VALUES
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("param1", adDate, adParamInput, , myDate)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("param2", adDate, adParamInput, , myDate)

    ' ASSIGN RECORDSET TO RESULT
    Set adoDbRs = .Execute
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some research on CTE and report back if I need more help :)

Comment: Hey this looks like it works! but I had some questions!

Playing around and trying to add more columns to your select query right below the max(convert_____, they don't appear on the results when running it.
I'm not sure why,   I'm also not understanding what those two parameters you are setting are actually doing in the grand scheme of things

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, CTEs were introduced to the SQL standard in 2003 and well-known beyond SQL Server. Re columns, all columns of the CTE named *reporttable2* should show since we use asterisk `*` in final `SELECT` statement. Ideally, you use [actual column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful). Re parameters, if you see the SQL string in VBA, there are two `?` (qmarks) which serve as placeholders that VBA later binds values, *myDate*, by qmark position to before executing query.

Comment: Hm I must be missing something then, I will play around with it further, thanks for the help!